# iepy django Environment variable JAVAHOME not defined

Tags: java, django, ubuntu, java-home

birdmw@birdmw-thinkpad:~/Desktop/nlp/iepy$ sudo iepy --create iepy
Environment variable JAVAHOME not defined.

I am having this problem with package IEPY. It is Django and Java related.

I feel like I have tried everything to set the JAVAHOME path but nothing works:

birdmw@birdmw-thinkpad:~/Desktop/nlp/iepy$ echo $JAVAHOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
birdmw@birdmw-thinkpad:~/Desktop/nlp/iepy$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
birdmw@birdmw-thinkpad:~/Desktop/nlp/iepy$ which java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

sudo vim /etc/environment
 PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
 JAVAHOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
 JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

birdmw@birdmw-thinkpad:~/Desktop/nlp/iepy$ sudo iepy --create iepy
Environment variable JAVAHOME not defined.
birdmw@birdmw-thinkpad:~/Desktop/nlp/iepy$ Of course it is, am I taking crazy pills?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to use good formatting. You can use the `{}` button to make code blocks and there is a preview before you submit your changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longer answer has to do with the use of `sudo`.  But to just get you going, you should/can use this:

```
JAVAHOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java iepy --create iepy
```

If you **have** to use `sudo`, you can do:

```
sudo JAVAHOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java iepy --create iepy
```

Comment: It worked thanks! I don't know why though, I thought sudo was just a privilige thing.